# Как работает интерфейс OnClickListener?

Tags: java, android

Подскажите, как работает эта часть кода.

Дело в том, что мне не понятно, как при передаче безымянного объекта, если я правильно понимаю, конструктору объекта родительского класса вызывается метод `onClick()`?

```
    mCrowsCounterButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mInfoTextView.setText("Я насчитал " + ++mCount + " ворон");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> как при передаче безымянного объекта, если я правильно понимаю, конструктору объекта родительского класса вызывается метод onClick?

У вас нет здесь никакого конструктора объекта родительского класса. 
View.OnClickListener() - это имя типа, а точнее, интерфейса. Здесь View не родительский класс, а внешний (ну или как это называется в Java), и какого-то значения этот класс в данном коде не играет, а его конструктор здесь ни коим образом не вызывается. 
В Java нет такой удобной штуки, как события, поэтому вместо них используют интерфейсы.. По сути события - это синтаксический сахар, а потому вещь не обязательная, хотя и удобная.

Работает это так: для обработки клика нужен некий метод-обработчик с такой сигнатурой:

```
void onClick(View v)
```

который что-то там будет делать, выполняя обработку клика. Так как "просто метод"  в Java передать нельзя (по крайней мере до появления там лямбд), для этого используется интерфейс, в котором объявлен метод с этой сигнатурой. Экземпляр анонимного класса, реализующего этот интерфейс, передается в метод **setOnClickListener**. Таким интерфейсом является например **View.OnClickListener**. Передавая его инстанс в setOnClickListener вы гарантируете компилятору, что тот сможет вызвать у этого интерфейса метод onClick и тем самым выполнить обработку клика. А уж что за логика будет находиться в этом методе (и соответственно, как этот клик будет обрабатываться), это решаете вы сами.

Comment: Можно ли как аргумент в метод setOnClickListener() подставить просто объект некоего класса, который уже применяет интерфейс View.OnClickListener() ?

Answer (score 0):

Что такое `безымянный объект`? Возможно имелось в виду анонимный класс?

Конструктор тут вообще не фигурирует. У родительского объекта, он уже давным давно отработал.

Метод `onClick` вызовет система, когда получит сообщение о том что пользователь нажал польцем на View `mCrowsCounterButton`.