# Обработчик OnClickListener

Tags: java, android

В андроид можно создавать экземпляры интерфейсов?
Встречается часто код:

```
OnClickListener oclBtnOk = new OnClickListener();
```

Насколько я понял, создается экземпляр интерфейса. В JAVA вроде так делать нельзя. Разъясните пожалуйста

Comment: Ну раз встречается, значит можно. Это называется анонимным классом. Вот здесь похожий вопрос - http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/438981/181119. Про анонимные классы здесь - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html

Answer (score 3):

Очевидно, что это не интерфейс. Если код скопирован верно, то создается экземпляр класса (объект), который расширяет OnClickListener. Это наглядный пример почему давать непродуманные имена плохо. 
Для внесения ясности приложу код. (так не надо делать)

```
private class OnClickListener implements View.OnClickListener{

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю где вы могли такой код встречать, но компилятор ругается на такую запись, так как экземпляры интерфейсов создавать нельзя. Можно только так, но это уже будет экземпляр анонимного класса, который реализует интерфейс:

```
OnClickListener oclBtnOk = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //your code
        }
    };
```